# Cannot run my java class file in Excel VBA

Tags: java, vba, excel

please help. I can't run this file in Excel VBA even though I've already checked the Windows Script Host Object Model and Microsoft Word 15.0 Object Library, there's an error Sub or Function not defined, what should I'm going to do?

Here's the screenshot:
[image]

Comment: Why a `java` tag for this question?

Comment: The function `RunProgram` is private to `Sheet1`. So Either move it to `Module1` or make it `Public` and call it with `Sheet1.RunProgram`.

Comment: @FlorentB. I've already did what you said but it is still have an error.

Answer (score 0):

Try somethink like this :

```
Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
dim a
a = "C:\Program Files (x86)\MyProgram\MyApplication.jar"
WshShell.Run "java -jar " &  chr(34) & a & chr(34)
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the response, uhm where will I put that? In module1?

Comment: For example or in a new function, and you can create a button to call the function

Comment: Can you give all the codes in sheet1 and module1? please.. so it will work.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't specified correct command to execute your java class. Below is invalid command

```
java -java "C:\\Hello.java" Margus
```

First you need to compile you java file using

```
javac Hello.java
```

Then, specify command as

```
java Hello Margus
```

Assuming, you VBA script and class file exists in same directory

Comment: Can you give all the codes for sheet1 and module1? please.. So it will work.